# Can anyone explain how to insert emojis to VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, unicode, emoji

In VBA Excel to print `" & Chr(34) & "` is used to define `"`. I have searched and it said 34th character is `"`, as per [this website](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/rexx/htm/symbols.htm).

In same way for  Thumbs Up Sign the code is

```html
&#128077; &#x1f44d;
```

I have tried:

```vb
" & Chr(#128077) & "  
" & Chr(128077) & "  
" & Chr(#x1f44d) & "
" & Chr(x1f44d) & "
```

But it says error as a Syntax error or Expecting ) or Invalid Argument

Can anyone suggest me the solution

Answer (score 5):

In Excel, characters are stored using Unicode `UTF-16`. "Thumbs up" corresponds to the Unicode character [`U+1F44D`, encoded as follows](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d/index.htm):

> in UTF-16 (hex) : 0xD83D 0xDC4D (d83ddc4d)
>
> in UTF-16 (decimal) : 55357 , 56397

All those characters which are not the classic latin characters (ASCII) are to be handled with `chrW` and `ascW`.

So, in your case

```
ChrW(55357) & ChrW(56397)
or
ChrW(&HD83D) & ChrW(&HDC4D)
```

would produce thumbs up. Also note that you won't get that in the VBA IDE. You will have to put it in a worksheet to see it.

**Clarification**

```
' Puts a thumbs up symbol in A1
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ChrW(55357) & ChrW(56397)

' Will not produce a thumbs up symbol, since VBA can't handle it
Debug.Print ChrW(55357) & ChrW(56397)

' Will not produce a thumbs up symbol, since VBA can't handle it
MsgBox ChrW(55357) & ChrW(56397)
```

**HTML**
If you want the thumbs up to be in HTML, then do like this:

```
HtmlString = "<p>something something &#128077;</p>"
Print #1, HtmlString ' <-- replace with your output method
```

(`&#128077;` or `&#x1f44d;`)

Comment: I have tried with " & ChrW(56397) & "   it throws as https://prnt.sc/myprap

Comment: I need to use in Vba Editor for Excel., i'm confused /

Comment: @DineshS - I have added some clarification above

Comment: `You must use decimal numbers` - why? `128077` is `&h1f44d&`.

Comment: No, I take that back. But you have to use the right syntax. For the numbers, I recommend https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d/index.htm. 128077 is the html entity number, which can't be used here.

Comment: I am printing into Html file using 
Print #1, " & Chr(34) & "  
How do I insert thumbs up in the above scenario,
even I was not able to paste emoji directly into a cell and call it into the code.,
since the emoji was not clear
https://ibb.co/GtPn1BL

Comment: It works. But when i try emoji 1 - its send just symbol 1.. How i can send emoji 1?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I think I can clarify it. Go to https://emojiguide.org/ and search for your emoji, for example "Star-Struck". Scroll down to **UTF-16 hex** and copy the code "0xd83e 0xdd29". Now replace "0x" with "&H" and set the rest to capital letters, like this `Range("A1") = ChrW(&HD83E) & ChrW(&HDD29)`.